# Is it more efficient check for empty values in php?

Tags: php, performance

In some cases when an empty value is not an issue, I do not check the variable.

For example:

```
$fruits = array("apple","banana");
    foreach ($fruits as $a) {
    $res .= ", $a";
}

echo "This are the fruits you like: ".$res;
```

Now, if $fruits happens to be empty, this is not an problem, simply the list will be empty (I know this is not very elegant and I could use a conditional statement to change the answer to "You do not like any fruit", but it’s just an example!).

I’m just wondering if in general it is more efficient to check if the array is empty anyway. 
In short, is this better from a performance point of view or isn’t there any actual difference:

```
if (!empty($fruits)) foreach()... and so on
```

Thanks,
kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any performance gains would be negligible. This is called micro-optimization. Focus on writing good code and stop worrying about micro-optimizations.

I'd go for something like this:

```
if(!empty($fruit) && is_array($fruit)){
    echo "This are the fruits you like: " . implode(", ", $fruit);
}
```

Comment: I would do the same thing, except I would have an additional condition: `if (is_array($fruit) && !empty($fruit))` considering `$fruit` can be `array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what the array is being populated by. For example, if it's user input, you may need to make sure it's not empty, otherwise, if it isn't needed, then don't. It's definitely on a per-case basis.

Also, be careful when using empty(); if the value is 0, then it will return true even though a value is present. You can use strlen() to get around this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo is_array($array) ? implode(', ', $array) : false;
```

single line solution..

or you can use, count.

eg: count($array) > 0 ....

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `isset()` that will check if the variable has a value 0 or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the array `$fruits` is empty, and then use the `implode` as Wayne suggested.

```
  if(!empty($fruits)){
   echo "This are the fruits you like: " . implode(", ", $fruits);
 }
```

`is_array` is not really necessary, IF you have initialized the array as `$fruits = array();` before these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case I wouldn't think it would make a huge difference. However if it was empty $res would never be declared and this may cause an error and errors are always bad.